# Ansible - Copy a text file from windows server A to window server B after running playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am a beginner at Ansible world.
If I would like to copy a text file from windows server A to window server B, there is an error shown below.

[image]

This is my playbook. Do you have any idea about it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

what you did is  right by using the copy module , but there are a problem related to module name and their attribute .

you can copy file from server A ====> to server B using this code:

```yaml
- name: Copy a single file from server A to Server B
  ansible.windows.win_copy:
    src: /srv/myfiles/foo.conf # your local file
    dest: C:\Temp\renamed-foo.conf # your remote file without the @ip address
```